# What is the function of CFBundleIdentifier presence in plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bundle-identifier

`CFBundleIdentifier` key/value doesn't appear in **plist** file when creating iOS project app using **Xcode 13**.

If I can remember correctly. prior to Xcode 13 the value was there.

Now, changing the `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` in Build Settings tab would reflect on the bundle id field on the General Tab.

What was the use of CFBundleIdentifier in plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What was the use of CFBundleIdentifier in plist file?

The same as it is now! The only change is that you now construct the plist file at build time using build settings, rather than using a "model" plist file in the project.

Comment: Fascinating, can I know @matt where I can find such information? How you know it? Where did u read it first time. Is it release notes or something?

Comment: so if I set the value now to a static value in plist. that means the value in build settings would be useless right or what? @matt